# how to UUID create and call?

Tags: python, django, uuid

I am making an app, how can I issue and call UUID when first running the app?
I'm using Python, Django .
And I have to make a call to the URL for the front.

```
import uuid
print uuid.uuid4()
2eec67d5-450a-48d4-a92f-e387530b1b8b
```

How to make it is like this.

Need to create a model?

Comment: What do you want to do? Your question is not very descriptive... _"I have to make a call to the URL for the front"_ does not exactly describe whatever you want to do... For what purpose do you want a uuid would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just like that, calling the method `uuid.uuid4()` will return an object that you can assign to a variable and use it in the code...

```
import uuid
myUuid = uuid.uuid4()

print(myUuid)

send(myUuid)
check(myUuid)
...
```